# Override Date.prototype.xyz function

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype

Kindly don't mark it as duplicate. I searched a lot and there is no such question here. There are similar ones but not the same.

I tried and also looked around to find a solution for this but at last I thought, I should ask it here.

Without parameter

> `>`new Date().toLocaleString()
>
> "6/30/2016, 11:33:19 PM"

With  parameter, `"zh-Hans-CN"` can have any valid value, just for the sake of question.

> `>`new Date().toLocaleString("zh-Hans-CN")
>
> "2016/6/30 下午11:33:48"

I actually want to change the behaviour of this function in such a way that, it should return output as in second case but without any input argument. like

> `>`new Date().toLocaleString()
>
> "2016/6/30 下午11:33:48"

So the idea was, somehow override that function and call existing function from inside overriding function with a param.

like

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleString = function () {
    return this.toLocalString("zh-Hans-CN");
}
```

But it is wrong because this function is calling itself, causing infinite recurrsion casing this error.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)

So this is one example, question is how we can override this functionality using the same prototype function. Maybe there is a way to detach the actual function first and then override it. Your help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a anonymous function to save `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` as  a reference then return a function that returns  the `reference` thats binds to that function context.

```js
Date.prototype.toLocaleString = (function (ref) {
  return function(){
    return ref.bind(this)('zh-Hans-CN');
  }

})(Date.prototype.toLocaleString)
```

Comment: That's awesome. It will be great if you can throw some light, hows it's working. I know you already explained but if it can be improved. Thanks a lot